# Laravel hasMany relationship filter: Unknown column error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm building a scheduling app where time blocks are associated with specific classrooms. The classroom model has a hasMany relationship with the block model, which is set up correctly, according to the Laravel documentation. In this particular instance, I am trying to find rooms with empty time blocks in a specified time range. Sadly, even though it seems perfectly correct to me when looking at the docs, this implementation gives me an error when calling the controller function.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rooms.id' in 'where clause'

```
$rooms->whereDoesntHave('blocks', function ($query) {
    $query->where('day', '=', \request('day'))
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('startTime', '<=', \request('startTime'))
                ->where('endTime', '>', \request('startTime'));
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('endTime', '>', \request('endTime'))
                ->where('startTime', '<', \request('endTime'));
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('startTime', '>', \request('startTime'))
                ->where('endTime', '<', \request('endTime'));
        })->get();
});

$searchedRooms = $rooms->get();
```

This piece of code is causing me significant issues; I do some other filtering for the rooms beforehand, but that one works perfectly fine when I omit this part of the code.

Comment: can you do `dd($rooms->toSql())` and share the result of that (or just check what's going on with it). It's possible that you've removed something in the previous part of the query that a `whereDoesntHave` needs in order to work